# Get all child div values in jquery AJAX response

Tags: jquery

I need to get all child div values from the AJAX response which contains the following format.

```
var jqxhr = $.post('<%= url_for :action => :friend_list %>', { id: fid }, 
    function(data){
        var stripped_data = $(data).html().trim();
        var top_name = $(stripped_data).find('div.toppings_name').html();  
    });
```

In the alert of stripped_data contains the following format.

```
<div id="toppings>
  <div class="toppings_name">a</div>
  <div class="toppings_name">b</div>
  <div class="toppings_name">c</div>
</div>
```

I tried using `.find()` method but getting the first child value only. How to get all the values from the parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using `html` which is meant for use on a single element but actually using it on a collection.  Instead you want the html contents of the outer div.  Try this instead

```
var top_name = $(stripped_data).find('#toppings').html();
```

If you are looking for each of the names in the div list though, try the following

```
var all = [];
$(stripped_data).find('div.toppings_name').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).text();
  all.push(name);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use jQuery's `.each()` function in conjunction to get all the values:

```
$(stripped_data).find('div.toppings_name').each(function() {
    // Process each topping here
});
```